# Assert correct scrolling position with selenium in python

Tags: python, django, selenium, pytest-django

I am running a django app and in that scope I have a page with a navigation bar and when I click on my `contact`-tab this automatically scrolls down to my contact-section.

I am trying to test this behaviour with selenium but I can't seem to figure out how I can test the actual position of the page. Or, in other words, I want to verify that the page actually scrolled down to the contact-section.

Right now I am doing this:

```
 def test_verify_position(
        self, browser, live_server
    ):
        """"""
        browser.get(live_server.url)
        contact_section = browser.find_element_by_id("contact").click()

        assert ????
```

I think I somehow have to get the current scroll location-coordinates. I know I can get the location of an element using `.location`. But the relative position of an element is always the same no matter the scroll-position. I tried this to debug:

```
 def test_verify_position(
        self, browser, live_server
    ):
        """"""
        browser.get(live_server.url)
        e = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/section[4]/div/div[1]/h2/strong")

        location = e.location
        print(location)

        browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav-contact").click()

        e = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section[4]/div/div[1]/h2/strong")
        location = e.location
        print(location)
```

This prints the same coordinates for before and after the scroll.

I also searched the official doc https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/ but couldn't find a better solution or any solution for that matter.

Anyone knows how to do this? Help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to click on it and check if it moved there? Cause you can return the current scroll height to match with the element location. You could get x,y offset if you want to as well.

```
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
print(height)
nav = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav-contact")
location = nav.location
print(location)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",nav)
nav.click()
Assert.assertTrue(height.equals(location['y'])); 
#what the answer was
browser.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")
```

Comment: Thank you arundeep!! Yes I think this is what I want. I think it would even be enough for me to assert the scroll height after the click. But what happens is, that it is the same scroll Height before and after I click on the contact tab in the navbar. (even though a different part of the page is shown). Would yo have an idea why that is? It should be different right?

Comment: You could use something similar to rahul rai to scroll to the object to click it.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to assert that when I click the contact-tab it actually moves to the correct position because of the click. If I move there with test-code I won't assert that the actual click brought me there. I would like to assert the page-position after click has changed

Comment: Which I think should work with your code you recommended, I'm just confused why the scroll-position is the same before and after click

Comment: ah yes that must be it... but can I somehow get the page height instead of scroll height with js...? I tried to modify your code to `return document.body.height` but it gives me `None`

Comment: thank you so much. Hm, also this gives me the same values before and after click. Also not sure if it's the one I want :) Just need something that gives me different values for the page position before and after the click I guess

Comment: Try it with this it returns the location of the nav while scrolling to it.

Comment: you mean like `browser.execute_script("return this.body.offsetHeight")`?

Comment: return document.body.offsetHeight or document.offsetHeight

Comment: Ah ok yes I tried. `document.body.offsetHeight` gives me the same values before and after click. `document.offsetHeight` gives me `None`. But I think it **should** actually give me different values, right?

Comment: Try using the scrolling function i used

Comment: even when I use the scrolling function, same values before and after... no idea why

Comment: If you get the scrolling height before it should be different and after it should be the same.

Comment: hm ok I understand. So something is off. I also get a `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` when I run the code above now

Comment: Oh I misplaced the clicking.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I needed to pause this for a bit and look at it with a fresh pair of eyes. I managed to test this now with `browser.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")` This gives me different values for before and after the click. I really appreciate your help and the troubleshooting. Couldn't have done it without you two, so thanks alot.

Comment: Already upvoted both! If anyone wants to add this line to the solution I also be happy to accept the answer, would be happy to give credit to you guys

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :**  You can identify one of element in screen loading after click on Contact nav and wait till its visible.

```
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver.visibility_of_element_located, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '<xpath>')))
    except TimeoutException:
        assert False
```

Need to **Import:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Comment: Thank you rahul!  But it still gives me the same coordinates for before and after. The think is that the actual click(), `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav-contact").click()` already renders this exact section. So in fact there is no scrolling involved but the click already brings the user there

Comment: Oh I thought after clicking your page is loading and element e is the one which position you are after. So as you said after click on Contact tab you are scrolling to contact section. Can you locate any element in contact section n try to scroll to element using js like. browser.execute_script(“arguments[0].scrollIntoView();”,element). And then print element location

Comment: sorry if I am unclear. First I move to my landing page (`browser.get(live_server.url)`). I print the location. Second I click on the contact tab in the navbar (`...click()`). This moves to the contact section on the same page. I print the location. Both times the same location `{'x': 454, 'y': 2979}`. Also the same location when I try your suggestion `browser.execute_script(“arguments[0].scrollIntoView();”,element)`... But maybe I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: And what I actually want to assert is that the page is scrolled to at this specific position. That this part of the page is the part a user looks at

Comment: Okay it look like when your page is loading your previous elements are getting disappeared as result page height is remaining same. Also it is difficult to asset this way. Please see i have updated answer using is displayed method.

Comment: Thank you again Rahul. The problem with this is that this passes even before I even execute the `click`-method. And then afterwards it passes too.

Comment: @Micromegas one last attempt with visibility_of_element_located.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I needed to pause this for a bit and look at it with a fresh pair of eyes. I managed to test this now with `browser.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")` This gives me different values for before and after the click. I really appreciate your help and the troubleshooting. Couldn't have done it without you two, so thanks alot.